# Story-based questions, opinion-based questions, etc - where to go with those?

Tags: discussion

As [one of my questions](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/220544/this-dungeon-ruin-has-been-known-to-locals-for-ages-why-would-it-still-have-und) is on a brink of being closed (as "too story-based", presumably for the brief mentioning of the existence of a protagonist within the question), I thought it might be useful info to have, is there any popular sites that would be thematic for these types of worldbuilding questions instead? Maybe even mention those on the elaborations of "closed for opinions" and "closed for having a story" reasons to not make the user feel brushed off, and offering them an alternative.

Comment: Could you post a link to the doomed query?

Comment: @elemtilas Since I've edited out the word "protagonist" from the question, the number of VTC's for being story-based went from 4 to 1, so it's not quite doomed anymore. https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/220544

Comment: If the proposal ever becomes reality, the [Codidact counterpart of WB](https://meta.codidact.com/posts/283318/283335) would be the ideal place for fitting world & story together.

Comment: @elemtilas, from the page you linked: {it is not within the scope of the community to write a story for participants. Thus, a question asking, "I have the following five options, which one should my character take?" is off-topic while a question asking, "I'm working on a list of options my character can choose from, I already know he'll take this one..., Can you help me flesh out a list with the following conditions and restrictions?" would be on-topic. To this end, questions of the form "what should my character/nation/entity do next?" are off-topic.}

Comment: Maybe it would be a good idea to devise a sound definition of worldbuilding. When I search for that on this site, there are some topics from 2013-2014.. but it seems that debate did not result in a clear definition of the subject, published in "how to ask a question?" . I agree with Darth, closure seems a bit arbitrary now. Some weapons questions are accepted, some are not. Most creature design do not include a world.. and most times these are accepted as on-topic. Do we cover the tags ? Or do we cover the "worldbuilding" subject? And if it is both ways.. what's the actual reason to close ?

Comment: @Darth If I were to choose a reason to close, that'd be for being opinion-based. Not that I would choose to close in the first place. It's the same kind of story as your other question : intentions to avoid fishing for ideas. Wait, now that I think about it, it's perhaps more fishing for intentions than ideas that cause issues...

Comment: @Goodies -- Sounds like you're cooking up a Meta question!

Comment: VTC reasons on Worldbuilding seems arbitrary. Magic questions are allowed without a bat of an eye, but sci-fi scenario questions get VTC for being opinion based with no factual answer. If people wanted purely factual answers absent theory or imagination of any kind they would be at the science stack exchange, not world building.

Comment: You could try Reddit. They are a bit more relaxed and more welcoming when it comes to questions related to the story.